# Calling mutator from other class to change attribute of type vector<string>

Tags: c++, string, vector

So I have a class making clients, and one of the attributes of those clients is the following:

```
vector<string> *name_set;
```

and each string in that vector is the name of another client.

So I'm doing something later on where I want to add a string/name on to the end of the name_set.

```
//just used to select the first client in the vector of type <Client> later on
int other_client = 0;

// this gets the vector <string> of all the names in a given client's name set
vector<string> new_name_set = client.back().getNameSet();

// this adds the new client name to the name_set made previously
new_name_set.push_back(client[other_client].getFullname());

// now I want to change the name_set of the last client in the client vector using my mutator

members.back().setNameSet(const new_name_set);
```

The error I get on xcode states only 'Expected expression' with a small arrow under the word 'const'

my mutator, for reference is:

```
void Clients::setNameSet(const vector<string> nameSet){
    *name_set = nameSet;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have that const there? It's not legal. Just remove it.

Comment: When I remove it, I get an error still saying: member function 'setNameSet' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const value_type', but function is not marked as const

Comment: Well adding a syntax error won't fix that :-) The problem isn't with the argument, it's with `members.back()` which appears to return a const object/reference. You can't call non-const members on it.

Comment: Oh I see! Could you think of a work-around with what you know about my project so far?

Comment: Not without knowing what type `members` is.

Comment: sorry, members is supposed to say 'clients' there.

Comment: it's type vector<clients>. So is a vector which contains all my clients

Comment: Then look at the vector class docs, and look for accessors that return non-const references.

Comment: Just changed my accessor (getNameSet) and deleted the const from that, working now! Best day ever. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
members.back().setNameSet(const new_name_set);
```

Should be:

```
members.back().setNameSet(new_name_set);
```

Comment: I've removed now, but I now get an error that says… member function 'setNameSet' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const value_type', but function is not marked as const

Comment: The `members` variable is const, I guess.  You can't set to it then.